# Allocate more memory cucumber-js

Tags: javascript, selenium, cucumber, protractor, cucumberjs

How do you allocate more memory when running cucumber-js tests from the command line? Is there a specific tag or would you do it in your step-def files?

Answer (score 0):

You should ask this question on the cucumber mailing list, because the authors of cucumber js will see it.